# Issue "Could not render n, see the console" in Swagger with Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, swagger, code-documentation

In laravel 5.8 my swagger documentation is displaying fine but when I enter execute then its coming with 'Could not render n, see the console.' error.
[image]

**composer.php**

```
 "darkaonline/l5-swagger": "5.8.*"
```

what can be the reason? anyone please suggest. TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make it okey by passing the request through that functions.

```
 requestInterceptor: function(request) {
      request.headers['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = '{{ csrf_token() }}';
      return request;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar issue but with Laravel 7.26.x. Issue related to the CSRF Token.

On my swagger blade I removed from the body

```
requestInterceptor: function () {
    this.headers['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = '{{ csrf_token() }}';
    return this;
},
```

and added instead

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Also don't forget to add in your web routes

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::get('api/documentation', '\L5Swagger\Http\Controllers\SwaggerController@api')->name('l5swagger.api');
});
```